# 2D elastic collision not working properly

Tags: java, game-physics

I've have this code and the balls bounces around, but when I apply some gravity I want them to stay on top of each other. But instead they slowly fall through.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXJoU.png)

Here's my code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
        Ball curr = balls.get(i);


        if (curr.getPos().getX() - curr.radius <= 0) {
            curr.getVel().mul(-0.9, 1);
            curr.getPos().set(curr.radius, curr.getPos().getY());
        } else if (curr.getPos().getX() + curr.radius >= WIDTH) {
            curr.getVel().mul(-0.9, 1);
            curr.getPos().set(WIDTH - curr.radius, curr.getPos().getY());
        }

        if (curr.getPos().getY() - curr.radius <= 0) {
            curr.getVel().mul(1, -0.9);
            curr.getPos().set(curr.getPos().getX(), curr.radius);
        } else if (curr.getPos().getY() + curr.radius >= HEIGHT) {
            curr.getVel().mul(1, -0.9);
            curr.getPos().set(curr.getPos().getX(), HEIGHT - curr.radius);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < balls.size(); j++) {
            if (j == i) continue;
            Ball other = balls.get(j);
            double xDist = curr.getPos().getX() - other.getPos().getX();
            double yDist = curr.getPos().getY() - other.getPos().getY();
            double distance = xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist;
            if (distance <= (curr.radius + other.radius) * (curr.radius + other.radius)) {
                double xVel = other.getVel().getX() - curr.getVel().getX();
                double yVel = other.getVel().getY() - curr.getVel().getY();
                double dot = xDist * xVel + yDist * yVel;
                if (dot > 0) {
                    double colScale = dot / distance;
                    double xCol = xDist * colScale;
                    double yCol = yDist * colScale;
                    double mass = curr.mass + other.mass;
                    double weightCurr = 2 * other.mass / mass;
                    double weightOther = 2 * curr.mass / mass;
                    curr.getVel().add(weightCurr * xCol, weightCurr * yCol);
                    other.getVel().sub(weightOther * xCol, weightOther * yCol);
                    curr.getPos().add(curr.getVel().mul(DMP));
                    other.getPos().sub(other.getVel().mul(DMP));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A line should be inserted after this one:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < balls.size(); j++) {
       if( j == i ) continue;
```

Otherwise each ball is balling with itself.

Another potential source of error is the way balls are bounced against the four walls and each other: The first ball is wall-checked and then bounces against all others, and only then are all others wall-checked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
    Ball curr = balls.get(i);
    // wall checks
}  // wall-check done!

 for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
     Ball curr = balls.get(i);
     for (int j = 0; j < balls.size(); j++) {
         if( j == i ) continue;
         // ball - ball check ...
     }
 }
```

Also, if ball 1 passes the check with ball 2, but ball 2 is then pushed away by ball 3 into the radius of ball 1, overlaps may occur. Not sure how to cope with this: repeat ball-ball until no corrections are necessary?

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @JeppeSRC There simply isn't enough code to try and repro it. I've added another suggestion based on gut feeling.

Comment: Aw well thank you for trying, I'll continue googling, see if I can find something useful.